# Devise login with username, signin failure not showing error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have been trying to login with username so followed this tutorial

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Sign in with username and signup is happening perfectly. But if i try to sign in with invalid username or password, it is not showing any error messages.

i have <%= devise_error_messages! %> mentioned in sessions/new.html.erb.
Also tried binding.pry resource doesn't have any errors attached to it.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

other details same as mentioned in the url.

Comment: Is login field available in users model. Actually whatever you define in authentication_keys in devise.rb, should be there in the model. if you have username in model, define it there in devise.rb. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not displaying the flash messages.
So add the below in your application.html.erb above <%= yield %>

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "flash #{key}" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually devise logi errors are work with flash. so ad flash to your code
like: <%= flash %>